# head tag is in a locked region

Tags: php, html, include, dreamweaver

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

        <head>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">


        <title>Codey Buzz's</title>

        <link href="stylesheets/public.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- mobile -->
        <link href="../stylesheets/mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width:800px)">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/script.js"></script>
        <script src="javascripts/SpryMenuBar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/clearbox.js"></script>
    <link href="stylesheets/SpryMenuBarVertical.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var MenuBar1 = new Spry.Widget.MenuBar("MenuBar1", {imgRight:"SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarRightHover.gif"});
    </script>
    <script type="text/xml">
    <oa:widgets>
      <oa:widget wid="2648024" binding="#OAWidget" />
    </oa:widgets>
    </script>
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="head" -->
    <!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
        </head>


        <body>

            <header>
                <h1>Inspiring Message</h1>
            </header>
            <div id="content">
```

the above html is my `header.php` file which i include on every page of my website.

I include this with

```
<?php include("includes/header.php"); ?>
```

at the top of every page.

In dreamweaver CS6 I get an error that my head tag is in a locked region. I did some research and came across stuff involving a template, though I didn't use a template, I hand wrote my code minus the widgets I'm trying to add. How do I unlock this? I've tried commenting out my head secion in my `header.php` file and adding a new head section on my index.php page but it still gives me the same error. I don't want to insert the widget into a new page. I want to "unlock the head tag". I added the templatebegineditable in hopes of fixing it though it doesn't work in any variation Ive tried. around the title, before the end of the head tag etc. The support on Adobe for fixing this problem is beyond idiotic, everyone ends up manually inserting the content and changing every link and script directory.

anyone know the fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

By default, your template should have an editable region in it just before the closing  tag. It looks like this:

```
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="head" -->
<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
```

Dreamweaver should be able to find that editable region and insert the  tag there automatically.

Its Mentioned in Adobe Forums!

Comment: Quoting myself, "I added the templatebegineditable in hopes of fixing it though it doesn't work in any variation Ive tried. around the title, before the end of the head tag etc. The support on Adobe for fixing this problem is beyond idiotic". I tried it again to humor the suggestion, with no success. I appreciate your time though.